# CSS that shows the box model?

Tags: css, stylus

Is there a good way to use just css (or possibly js) to show the box model for an entire page?

Something in between what jeet.gs does (after you toggle it) and what the developer view shows on mouseover in chrome?

EDIT: To clarify, the issue I'm focusing on here is showing the existing margin/border/padding/box dimensions visually. An ideal answer would handle all of these, as an overlay over the existing page (e.g. not clobbering existing styles) or explain that is impossible! (I'm not worried about how to toggle.)

Also, I realize it might be more tractable if you can use a css preprocessor, like stylus, which allows "property lookup" (https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/variables.html). A solution using stylus would be fine -- I just added that as a tag. But I have not yet figured out how. Perhaps it's possible using that in combination with a multiple borders technique? (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/).

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a border around everything.  It would be simple enough to figure out margin and padding from there.

```
* {border: 1px solid black}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a css class used for debugging and attach via js to your desired divs.

Something like:

```
div.debug {
    border: 1px dotted red;
    background-color: green;
}
```

And in your javascript, you can do a function that toggles on and off, whenever you need to debug.

```
function toggleDebug(){
    var divList = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i = 0; i < divList.length; i++){
       divList[i].classList.toggle('debug');
    }
}
```

I made a jsFiddle exemplifying that: http://jsfiddle.net/4awqayc1/